# Format custom date by dayjs

Tags: javascript, date, time, dayjs

```
const dateString = '2020-05-14T04:00:00Z'
```

I want my output as:

```
9.10AM 12.07.23
```

In moment.js I have written as:

```
<div>{moment(value.col_createddate).format("h.mm A  DD.MM.YY")}</div>
```

But now I want in dayjs.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://github.com/KooiInc/es-date-fiddler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Day.js, you can achieve the desired output using the format method, similar to how you would in Moment.js. Here's how you can format the given dateString using Day.js:

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs');

const dateString = '2020-05-14T04:00:00Z';

const formattedDate = dayjs(dateString).format("h.mmA DD.MM.YY");

console.log(formattedDate);
```

This code uses Day.js to parse the dateString and then formats it according to your specified format: "h.mmA DD.MM.YY". The format method in Day.js works similarly to Moment.js for formatting dates.